# How do I programatically set QuillJS format settings to "normal" or "default" values?

Tags: javascript, quill

The documentation is very good, and it gives a lot of examples for different settings, e.g.

https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#formatting

```
quill.format('color', 'red');
quill.format('align', 'right');
quill.format('size', 'large');
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to format these to be the default values? quill.format('size', 'normal') doesn't work, etc

I could parse the string for the delta and manually do it, but I was wondering why the API wouldn't be there for something straightforward like this.

Answer (score 2):

This detail seems to be missing from the `format` call but the answer is the same as the [`formatText`](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#formattext) call: pass in `false` as the value.

To avoid ambiguity in Quill there cannot be two ways to represent the same thing so you cannot have size: 'normal' since omitting the value would mean the same thing.